# How can I set custom price in Checkout API

Tags: php, api, soap-api-v2

Is there a way I can apply a custom price in checkout cart using APIv2?

```
$product = array();
$product['sku'] = 'test'
$product['qty'] = 5;
// $product['price'] = 15;
$client->shoppingCartProductAdd($session, $cart, array($product));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default magento not provided this functionality. If you are required then customization default `shoppingCartProductAdd` api like this way.

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Cart_Product_Api extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Product_Api
{
    public function add($quoteId, $productsData, $store=null)
    {
       ...
       $result = $quote->addProduct($productByItem, $productRequest);
       if(isset($productItem['price']) && $productItem['price'] != null) {
           $result->setOriginalCustomPrice($productItem['price']);
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

You could then add price into the array of data in your API call like this.

```
array(
    "sku" => "sku1",
    "qty" => 1,
    "price" => 0.50,
)
```